# DotNet MAUI Blazor App build with razor class library (Android/iOS)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, build, maui-blazor

Certificate configured as per the guide-line. We are able to generate build without razor class library. When we try to generate build with razor class getting below error.

```
dotnet\sdk\6.0.400-preview.22301.10\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResoluti
on.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file '\Razo
rClassLibrary\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that
 you have included 'net6.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [C:/RazorClassLibrary\RazorClassLibrary.csproj]
```

Tried with below options

1. Removed obj folder
2. Restore `Nuget Package`
3. Visual Studio update
4. MSBuild update
5. Added `<RuntimeIdentifier>android-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

Spending more than two days, Really appreciate any guide to resolve this issue.

Comment: For the `NETSDK1005`,  here are some actions you can take that may resolve the error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1005

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks,  Tried this option but didnt work out. We can able to run in emulator. But we are facing this error while try to generate APK through command line(elease).

Comment: Have you tried other ways to generate the APK? Does this return the same error? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this

1. In Library project .csproj replace TargetFramework by plural ->  <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
2. In App project .csproj, I set android to API21, in my case with API31 didn't work.
3. In App project, right click, properties, Go to Android / Options / Package Sign, and complete complete info from keystore